# Datetime works in Windows, but not Debian

Tags: python, datetime, debian

When attempting to run this code i get an error on Debian, but it works on Windows.

```
def checkTime():
    while True:
        with open('date.txt') as tar:
            target = tar.read()
            current = str(datetime.strptime(str(date.today()),'%Y-%m-%d'))[:-9]
            if datetime.strptime(current, '%Y-%m-%d') >= datetime.strptime(target, '%Y-%m-%d'):
                doSomething()
        sleep(10)
```

It gives me this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

date.txt contains:

```
2013-03-21
```

Both systems have exactly the same date and time settings.

Comment: Why are you converting today's date to a string, then converting it back again to a datetime, then converting it to a string again, only to convert it back again to a datetime object?!

Comment: For science! Or a more realistic explanation is that i tend to over complicate things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date handling is way overcomplicated.

This should do fine on any platform:

```
with open('date.txt') as tar:
    target = tar.read().strip()
    if date.today() >= datetime.strptime(target, '%Y-%m-%d').date():
```

with the `.strip()` call removing any extraneous whitespace (such as `\r` lines from a windows-format `\r\n` CRNL combo).

I'm not sure why you go through such great lengths to convert todays date to a string, to parse it to a `datetime` object, then to convert it to a string again. In any case, the *default* string format for `datetime.date` objects follows ISO8601, matching the `%Y-%m-%d` format:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> str(datetime.date.today())
'2013-03-21'
```

To convert a `datetime.date` object to a `datetime.datetime` object, use the `.combine()` method and add a `datetime.time` object in the mix:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 21, 0, 0)
```

By calling `.date()` on a `datetime.datetime` instance you can get a `datetime.date` object again:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().date()
datetime.date(2013, 3, 21)
```

Comment: Thank you. That explained it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because 'date.txt' contains Windows-style line endings ('\r\n'), but Unix (Debian) only processes '\n'.

Try opening your file with universal line ends:

```
open('date.txt','U')
```